# hibernate.cfg.xml not found error

Tags: hibernate

I am creating a web application with eclipse and I am using hibernate.

I am getting all the time this error: 
`org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found`.

I know that usually it is related to the location of the hibernate files but I changed the location from `src` to `build/classes` and to `webcontent/web-inf` and none of them seems to work.

I looked at the classpath file and it looks like the class path is the src folder and also the hibernate used to work and I didn't change anything in the locations of the file or the content of the pathclass file.

I just tried to add another table to the DB from the hibernate and now even after I deleted the changes it doesn't work.

Anyone have an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file available in the classpath of the VM the application will be running in. For example, in `WEB-INF/classes`.

You should check how your build process is outputting your classes. If, for instance, the `src` folder is compiled into `WEB-INF/classes`, you could place the file under `src`. Or, as Nim already pointed out, in `src/main/resources` if you're using Maven, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer putting it in `src/main/resources` and it gets copied across to `/WEB-INF/classes` on build.